# Java Swingnode Non Visible Image Save Bug

Tags: java, swing, javafx

On trying to take a snapshot of a BorderLayout which contains a SwingNode and JavaFX element, in the resulting image the Swingnode appears to be positioned in the lower right corner. I only get these results when the BorderLayout has not been seen. I have reproduced the problem in the test program below. When the export button is clicked, both the visible and non visible tabs should save to two different files with the same picture, but "invisible_file.png" picture should not be in the lower right corner.

tab_hide_document.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode?>


 <VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="TabController" prefHeight="500">
    <Button text="Export" fx:id="export" onAction="#handleExport"/>
    <TabPane fx:id="tabPane" minWidth="500">
    <tabs>
        <Tab text="visible tab" fx:id="visibleTab">
            <BorderPane fx:id="visibleBP" minHeight="300" minWidth="300">
            <center>
                <SwingNode fx:id="visibleNode"></SwingNode>
            </center>
            <bottom>
                <Slider></Slider>
            </bottom>
            </BorderPane>
        </Tab>   
         <Tab text="invisible tab" fx:id="invisibleTab">
            <BorderPane fx:id="invisibleBP" minHeight="300" minWidth="300">
            <center>
                <SwingNode fx:id="invisibleNode"></SwingNode>
            </center>
            <bottom>
                <Slider></Slider>
            </bottom>
            </BorderPane>
        </Tab>
    </tabs>
    </TabPane>
 </VBox>
```

TabController.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class TabController {

    @FXML
    private TabPane tabPane;

    @FXML
    private Tab visibleTab, invisibleTab;

    @FXML
    private SwingNode visibleNode, invisibleNode;

    @FXML
    private Button export;

    @FXML
    private BorderPane invisibleBP, visibleBP;

    private JPanel visiblePanel, invisiblePanel;

    public void initialize()
    {
        this.visiblePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        this.invisiblePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());       

        URL url = null;
        Image image = null;
        try{
            url = new URL("http://devstickers.com/assets/img/pro/d1i3.png");
            image = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (IOException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }

        ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon(image);
        this.visiblePanel.add(new JLabel(img1), BorderLayout.CENTER);       
        this.visibleNode.setContent(this.visiblePanel); 

        ImageIcon img2 = new ImageIcon(image);
        this.invisiblePanel.add(new JLabel(img2), BorderLayout.CENTER);         
        this.invisibleNode.setContent(this.invisiblePanel);

    }

    @FXML
    private void handleExport()
    {
        File visibleFile = new File("visible_file.png");
        File invisibleFile = new File("invisible_file.png");
        System.out.println("Export these pictures");
        try {
            ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(this.invisibleBP.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null), null), "png", invisibleFile);
            ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(this.visibleBP.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null), null), "png", visibleFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

TabExportTester.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class TabExportTester extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(TabController.class.getResource("tab_hide_document.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setHeight(1000);
            primaryStage.setWidth(1500);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```